# How many terms are created when multiplying two polynomials of different length

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I'm about to finish up a problem which asks me to figure out how many terms are present when multiplying two polynomials raised to different powers. However, there's one caveat: one of the polynomials contains one less terms in its simplified form than the other. I've figured out how many terms are in the respective expansions of each polynomial, but I don't know how to figure out how many terms will be produced by multiplying the two polynomials. Does anyone know how I can figure this out? Apologies if this is not specific, I can provide more details if need be.

I feel it's best I supply some extra information. Using arbitrary numbers, the question is essentially how many terms are in the expansion of $ \ (a+b+c)^{10}·(a+b+c+d)^2 \ . $ By the multinomial theorem, there are 66 terms in $ \ (a+b+c)^{10} \ $ and 10 terms in $ \ (a+b+c+d)^2 \ . $ I just can't figure out how many terms there are in $ \ (a+b+c)^{10}·(a+b+c+d)^2) \ . $

Comment: Substitute $u=a+b+c$. It makes the expression much cleaner.

Comment: @Trebor:  that hides much of what OP is looking for.

Comment: @RossMillikan Well, what prevents you from substituting back once you dealt with $d$ properly?

Answer (score 2):

The degree of the product is the sum of the degrees of the polynomials you multiply.  The minimum degree of a term is $0$, achieved whenever both polynomials have a constant term.  You then have to worry about whether any terms in between are missing, but have not supplied enough information to determine that.

Added:  now that you have explained that your polynomials have multiple variables, you need to assess all the mixed terms that can come up.  On the other hand, because all the terms are positive, you will never have one missing because the coefficients sum to $0$.  You need to count all the terms of the form $a^eb^fc^gd^h$ with $e+f+g+h \le 12,$ and $e,f,g \le 10, h \le 2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: how many terms without a $d$, how many with $d$ and how many with $d^2$?